# Ubuntu boot menu doesn't appear after selecting EFI Boot on MacBook Pro

Tags: boot, usb, macbook-pro, macosx

I tried the following guides.

- [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview)
- [Manual Approach](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_gl=1*llepbc*_gcl_au*MTQ5OTQ0MDMyMi4xNzA3NDU3MTQz&_ga=2.12244916.1813755729.1707691355-267015106.1707355555)
- [Set Secure Boot to No Security and Allow booting from external or removal media](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102522)

Unfortunately, the Ubuntu boot menu didn't show after choosing "EFI Boot". It stops at a black screen with nothing displayed.

Mac info:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- macOS Big Sur Version 11.6
- Processor 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- Memory 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

`/dev/disk2` is my USB.

```bash
diskutil info /dev/disk2
   Device Identifier:         disk2
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk2
   Device / Media Name:       SanDisk 3.2 Gen1

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 125.2 GB (125162225664 Bytes) (exactly 244457472 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   No


diskutil info /dev/disk2s1
   Device Identifier:         disk2s1
   Device Node:               /dev/disk2s1
   Whole:                     No
   Part of Whole:             disk2

   Volume Name:
   Mounted:                   No

   Partition Type:            Microsoft Basic Data
   File System Personality:   MS-DOS
   Type (Bundle):             msdos
   Name (User Visible):       MS-DOS (FAT)

   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported
   Disk / Partition UUID:     F45E2FA1-C5A6-4D79-876E-C8245AF921E0
   Partition Offset:          32768 Bytes (64 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                 5.0 GB (5032134656 Bytes) (exactly 9828388 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:        0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:         0 B (0 Bytes) (exactly 0 512-Byte-Units)

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (not mounted)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Removable
   Media Removal:             Software-Activated

   Solid State:               Info not available
```

No clues for troubleshooting this issue. Appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 0):

Updating MacOS to Sonoma fixed this issue.